# Annotate animation in plotly

Tags: python, animation, annotations, plotly

I am working on a filled area animation, very similar to:
[link](https://plot.ly/python/filled-area-animation/)

How to I add annotation that will be animated in accordance to the plot animation?
that is, how do I make the annotation text appear only when the point it is annotating appears?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to add

```
 layout = go.Layout(annotations= [dict( 'my Annotations')])
```

in to the **frame**

```
frames = [dict(data=[], traces=[], layout = go.Layout(annotations= [dict( 'my Annotations')]) )]
```

Then the **annotations** will be related to the **frame** and not to the parent layout